# UIScrollView and Constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to place a UIImageView at the top of a UIScrollView and when I constrain the UIScrollView to the sides of the View Controller and constrain the UIImageView to the top and make the width of the UIImageView equal to the UIScrollView it makes the UIImageView way wider than the UIScrollView, and much taller than expected.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

Preview:

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Check that following constraints are added to your view:**

1. Go to Storyboard -> Select your view
2. Now at right-bottom corner you can see small buttons to add constraints
3. Select **"Pin"** button
4. And mark all 4 constraints for all sides
5. Add all 4 constraints to your view

### EDIT

I have created one demo as you described.

### [ImageConstraint Demo](https://jumpshare.com/v/vx7EdgAPKW6w2Pnu94EF)

Set all constraints for `UIScrollView` and `UIImageView` and works perfectly.

Below are reference images for you.

### Storyboard:

[image]

### FOLLOW BELOW STEPS

**Step - 1 : In storyboard Select `UIView` -> Editor -> Resolve layout issues**

[image]

**Step - 2 : Repeat same to add constraint**

[image]

**Step - 3 : Select `UIScrollView` and add constraint from right-bottom corner**

[image]

**Step - 4 : Select `UIImageView` and add constraint for it.**

[image]

Comment: The problem here is with constraints, First remove all constraints and reassign constraints will resolved your problem.

Comment: @Varosion http://jmp.sh/XKaxAl2 ---> Link to download demo which i have created, This will help you.