# How to remove constraints on storyboard or menu

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to Xcode

I have lots of constraints on the object,

How to remove it on XCODE?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: you want to remove all constraints ?

Comment: Check this to solve constraint issues - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133144/uiscrollview-and-constraints/26135270#26135270

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Single Constraint**

To remove a single constraint just select it and hit delete.

**All constraint for a selected view(s)**

To remove constraints for a single view you select the view and hit the triangle button in the bottom right hand corner...

[image]

And hit "Clear Constraints" under the "Selected Views" part.

**All constraints in a View Controller**

To clear constraints for an entire View Controller do the same but hit "Clear Constraints" under the "All Views in ..." part.

**All constraints in a storyboard**

To clear all constraints in the Storyboard you'd be best to disable Auto Layout and then re-enable it for the Storyboard.

Answer (score 7):

Clear only selected view as below. which is clear only selected view constrain.

[image]

If you clear all constrain then selected below clear constrain.

You can click on constrain and press delete button also remove constrain individual.

Answer (score 1):

If you double click on the constraint in the side pane you've added a photo off, it'll locate it in the `Constraints` drop down on the left hand panel then just press delete on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Select the View that you want to remove constraints.

Go to Editor - > Resolve auto layout issue - > Clear Constraints

You can also find at the bottom right four button. third button is for the Resolve auto layout issue

Answer (score 0):

You can select your one by one constrains and press delete button or select the view you want to remove constrains now find a button at the bottom right corner of your story board name resolve auto layout issues there select the option clear Constraints.