# iphone 6 and 6 plus size scaling

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I am surprised how I was unable to find anything on this matter clearly addressing the How-To's rather than what to expect from Apple in the new iOS.

I am developing an application from scratch now and whenever I use the simulator of iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus in the xcode IDE, i get things misplaced in the screen such as shown in attached screenshots.

How can I build an app that would work on all iPhones the same way (autoscale or auto-resize)? If this has been answered before, please lead me to that topic/thread since I wasn't able to find anything decent and clear explaining this. 
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer is called autolayout, seems like you should start by reading documentation! This has been around since iOS 6. http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1
http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Comment: Follow my answer will guide you through - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133144/uiscrollview-and-constraints/26135270#26135270

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all about autolayouts. 
Here is good article for You: http://mobileoop.com/how-to-use-auto-layout-in-xcode-6-for-ios-7-and-8-development

Or the official Apple: [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: My +1 is really for `rckoenes` edit that included the Apple Documentation.