# IOS 8 Interface builder UITableViewCell alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am working on IOS app which got a UITabeView. I needed custom UITableViewCell, so i created .xib file to design it and linked it to my custom class. But I want a button to be aligned right and I cannot achieve it. The screenshot below shows my problem:

[image]

I am using autolayout. On the left side I have my .xib opened where I have a button. In the middle there is a simulator which show only a part of a button. Moreover, If a change orientation, absolute button position doesn't change (it becomes fully visible). On the right side you can see how I set constraints. Obviously, I did it in a wrong way, but I've tried everything and nothing helped. Different constraints, values, toggled autolayout - no effect.
How do I set up constraints so that my button is aligned right (on both orientations)?

P.S. I am using Swift.

Comment: Take a look on this answer, Hope you'll idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133144/uiscrollview-and-constraints/26135270#26135270

Answer (score 1):

you have to link your button to the view which contains it, you can press Ctrl and drag the mouse from your button to the view which contains it, Xcode will show a menu with the available constraints:

[image]

You have to select the constraints you need for setting up the position of the button, in your case it will be leading space to container, and in addition you should select width and height constraints. For selecting those constraints you can press this button on the bottom of the screen:

[image]

and in the following menu select the width and heigth constraints:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I did it, but now I have a button that is aligned to the left! I need it to be aligned to the right in both orientations.

Comment: yes, I applied trailing space constraint - and the same thing happened - as shown in the screenshot

Comment: you did remove the leading space constraint when you hav added the trailing constraint? and you have set the width constraint?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have trailing space constraint (equals 0) and width constraint (equals 46). In designer, my button has position (266;8) (aligned right) but i cannot see it in simulator! When I do `println(button)` i get output: `<UIButton: 0x7d18f2c0; frame = (546 8; 46 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d18f3c0>>` As I see, my button moves to the right, but I don't know why

Comment: Ok I got one similar issue some weeks ago, and I solved it but putting all the content of the cell (all the IBOutlets) inside a view, so you would have the cell, the content view, and then a view, with constraints to leading, trailing, top and bottom to the content view, and inside that view, you would place your button.

Comment: Thanx for the help, but I figured it out. The problem was that I haven't properly set UITableView constraints, not UITableViewCell ones