# Multiple items side-by-side on storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

What's the best way to put items side-by-side in Xcode 6/ios8 storyboard? I have constraints on each item but it doesn't show up in the way I want it to (see photo below) or if I put horizontal spacing between two items, one item gets pushed off the screen.

Any help will be very much appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have a look on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133144/uiscrollview-and-constraints/26135270#26135270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a leading constraint of 15 on "Take Photo", a trailing constraint of 15 on "View Photos", and a center horizontally within container constraint on "Welcome".