# Xcode 6 Interface Builder how do I make a UIView 100% width?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

Really basic question here I'm going through the docs and Apple videos but are yet to find out how to do it.

In Xcode 6 / iOS7/8 I have a UIview that I have dragged on an existing View sitting inside a new default ViewController.

All I want to do is in "Interface Builder" make this UIView I have dragged onto the screen "fill to 100% of the layout width", much like one would do with a webpage 100% width div wrapper, so that it automatically resizes its width on each device/layout it goes to.

What settings do I need to change to do that???, I don't seem to be able to figure it out.

I have been experimenting with constraints and size classes etc.

Any help would be great

Comment: You should better to use storyboard - See basic constraint setup here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133144/uiscrollview-and-constraints/26135270#26135270

Answer (score 0):

Create a constraint for all size classes that has an equal width to the ViewController. Or you can have contraints between the leading and trailing spaces with a constant equal to 0.

With the size classes you can have different constraints for different size classes. Ensuring these constraints are set in the "Base" size class means it will affect all size classes unless constraints for that specific size class are changed.