# How to Align Everything to Centre Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am trying to align all items to centre in Xcode as you can see here [image] but the problem is it looks un aligned in the other views [image]

I have tried to do this using constraints but these do not seem to make any difference after updating frames.

All I am trying to achieve is for everything shown to be centred across all devices.

Thanks.

Comment: Because you set the constraints incorrectly, just basic centering is really one of the easiest things to do with constraints.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVKwbLvk8Sg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27699791/3738720

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I aligned Horizontal and Vertical centre in container from the Editor -> Align menu and then added constraints using the constraints editor for Height and Size. I also setup some top constraints (using I bars in constraints editor) so the items below my image all lined up with it correctly.

For more info, watch [this Youtube video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=QVKwbLvk8Sg) provided by Lennet.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply pin them using the `horizontal center in container` constraint in Storyboard.

Select all your views and assign it here:

[image]