# Detail View on Storyboard too zoomed in - creates misaligned objects in simulator

Tags: xcode, button, storyboard, alignment, detailview

I have perhaps a beginner's question but have not found any solutions addressing this specific problem after searching endlessly on stackoverflow and other forums.

My detail view in the storyboard appears to be too zoomed in.  At this point, zooming in and out simply zooms in and out on the storyboard, but not the detail view specifically.

Indicators of this are that the alignment arrow to the left of my button is not positioned at half-latitude of the Detail View box, although when I align my button to this marker I do see a crosshair indicating that my button is "centered".

[Detail View - Further Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S1F8.png)

Upon simulation, it is apparent that using these crosshairs produces a run-time alignment far right and up from being centered.  Where my button is currently placed seems to be in the center of the simulator screen but would like my guidelines to allow the button to be centered using the guidelines suggested.

[Simulator View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfR5n.png)

A)  How do I "zoom out" within the Detail View so I can see the entire screen in the detail view?

B)  How can I center my object if the guidelines are inherently off-center?

Thank you so much for you advice and input.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using constraints to keep the various controls in place etc...?

If not try:

1. Select all elements in the UI of the detail view. Click on an empty spot somewhere in the View and press `CMD + A`.
2. Click on `resolve auto layout issues` at the bottom right of the Nib editor. (it's the right most icon)[image]
3. Click on `Clear Constraints`
4. Click on `resolve auto layout issues` again, then `Reset to Suggested Constraints`

From here, tweak your constraints as per the UI you're working with i.e. iPhone, iPad and whatever orientation it's in etc...

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Doing this appears to designate a "center" based on where I found my centered position to be by guessing and checking, so I could base all future object placement around this new "center box" that it has saved.  However, what would I do if I want something in the bottom left of my runtime screen?  I have no room to place anything down and left.

Comment: I guess this reverts back to my original question A)   How do I "zoom out" within the Detail View so I can see the entire screen within the detail view?

Comment: Dude I got It!!!  First constrain the size of the button.  Then with descending contraints:  Align center x to center x of button.  Align center y to center y of button.  BINGO!!  Thanks for your input.  @Adrian Sluyters.  It turns out the Detail View isn't a zoomable view, but the constraints simply adjust where the center of the view is.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention how I fixed the "too zoomed-in" problem.

In the storyboard controller, on the left navigator panel, within the file inspector, I simply unchecked "Use Size Classes" within the Interface Builder Document section.  My view controller changed into a normal iPhone shape and everything finally fit into place.